# How to replace rows with precedence in a mysql SELECT?

Tags: mysql, select, text, group-by

For example:

```
code, attr, val, precedence 
(0, 'key', 'value1', 1 )
(1, 'key', 'value2', 1 )
(2, 'key', 'value3', 1 )
(3, 'key2', 'value1', 1 )
(4, 'key3', 'value1', 1 )
(5, 'key', 'nothis', 2 )
(6, 'key', 'final_value', 3 )
```

I want to get something like this:

```
(6, 'key', 'final_value', 3 )
(3, 'key2', 'value1', 1 )
(4, 'key3', 'value1', 1 )
```

How to do it that in MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

Make join with list of maximum precedences for id. Something like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT attr, MAX(precedence) p FROM a) m
      ON m.attr = a.attr AND m.p = a.precedence
  GROUP BY a.attr;
```

grouping for only one row per attr; can be replaced by DISTINCT on SELECT clause